# converting .net graphics to java

Tags: c#, java, graphics

I was trying to convert this code from .NET to Java, but I couldn't convert these 4 lines. Please someone give me a suggestion how to convert this code:

```
this.pbSubSequence = (Image) new Bitmap(this.pbSubSequence.getWidth(),
                this.pbSubSequence.getHeight());
Image image = this.pbSubSequence.Image;
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(this.pbSubSequence.Image);
```

(`pbSubSequence` is a panel; I have four panels in this code and I have to draw sort of graph of ecg in all four of them which will be done by:

```
g.draw(new Line2D.Float(100f,100f,500f,500f)
```

(this line would run in a `for` loop)

Can someone help me write these lines in Java?

Comment: this `4` line code would become `40` lines of code in java..that's sure..

Comment: I see no `Image` member inside `Panel` class: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbxtbzd1(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: i tried to do the following with this code Image image=new Image(panel.width,panel.height,Image.bmp) ;g=image.getGraphics();Graphics2D graphics=(Graphics2D)g

Comment: The problem with this code is its not displaying anithing.i want something to link between panel and graphics so that the panel class knows dis is d graphics object to be used and the graphics class knows this is the panel where i m supposed to draw lines..pls answer this questions guys..

Comment: Give us the result of `pbSubSequence.GetType().ToString()`?

Answer (score 1):

To create bitmap in Java use: [BufferedImage()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#BufferedImage%28int,%20int,%20int%29)

To create Graphics from this image use [createGraphics()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#createGraphics%28%29)

The sense of your C# code I can't figure out.

Comment: can u simply write a code where there is one panel and image is inside the panel and draw inside the image using Graphics2D class(you may draw a simple triangle or a line)..The size of the image should be the size of panel..basicaly i m trying to draw ecg graph inside the image.

Answer (score 0):

That day i tried this code and i almost got what i wanted

```
BufferedImage image=new BufferedImage(pbSubsequence.getWidth(), pbSubsequence.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
            JLabel l=new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
            Graphics graphics = image.getGraphics();
            Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) graphics;
            pbSubsequence.add(l);
```

where pbSubsequence is a JPanel.So i was able to convert the code from .net to java.Still left with the testing part so cant be sure if the answer is right or no.Thanks guys for help